# Javascript Regular Expression to remove $ from Field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an amount field that I want to automatically remove any $ signs the user put in. For example, if they put in $50 -I want that to automatically change to 50. Same goes for if they put in $12.50 - it automatically changes it to 12.50.

I have the following script:

```
$('#searchAmt').on('keyup',function(){
var oldtxt = $(this).val();
var findtxt = '^[$]';
var newtxt = oldtxt.replace(new RegExp(findtxt, 'g'), '');
$(this).val(newtxt);
});
```

This works in removing the dollar sign, but it is also removing any decimal place the user puts in. So, using the examples above, it changes $50 to 50 but it changes $12.50 to 1250.

It is worth noting that the input field I'm using this for has an input type of number. In Safari & Chrome, this prevents the user from using a $ - but in Firefox and IE, the user can still put in a $.

Comment: It seems there is some other piece of code that removes the dot. `^[$]` only matches a `$` symbol at the start of the string.

Comment: What happens if they put in `£`? Isn't it better to look for numbers and keep that.

Comment: Please clarify by adding your relevant code, or people will be posting irrelevant answers. Please check the `keydown` function code.

Answer (score 2):

`.replace` also accepts a string as an argument, instead of just Regular Expressions. Try this:

```
var oldtxt = $(this).val();
var newtxt = oldtxt.replace("$", "");
```

This will remove `$`.

Alternatively, you can remove everything that's not a number or decimal with this:

```
var newtxt = oldtxt.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

It doesn't account for a number with multiple periods. To get rid of those, try this, which will leave only the last occurrence of a period:

```
var newtxt = oldtxt.replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=.*\.)/g, "");
```

I like RegEx.

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution, but after more testing it looks like the issue with the decimal occurs with the $(this).val(newtxt). I'm thinking I might need to rethink how to prevent a $ from being entered.

Comment: @rmlumley use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: @vlaz I am. It works perfectly in Safari & Chrome. The issue is Firefox & IE will still allow you to type in a $.

Comment: @rmlumley then I suggest looking at a validation library instead of doing it yourself. As I said mentioned on the question, "removing `$`" doesn't mean you get a valid number. Users can type in `£` or `€` or they may enter the amount as `10 000.32` or they could do `47,50` or they can enter `nine`. Yeah, the last one isn't an exaggeration, either - you can and probably will have people genuinely putting that in. Yes, even if you have a giant message saying NUMBERS ONLY! Validation is a solved problem, don't try to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```js
console.log('$50\n$60'.replace(/[$]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[$]')
```

or

```
var regex = new Regex('^\\\$')
```

This will only remove the `$` sign if it occurs at the start of the string.

**output from chrome console**

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[$]')

var oldtxt = "$12.50"

newtxt = oldtxt.replace(regex, '')

"12.50"
```

Comment: `The dollar sign needs to be escaped` no, it doesn't - the dollar sign loses its special meaning inside square brackets. It _either_ needs to be escaped _or_ needs to be inside `[]` having both is not required and it simply serves to clutter the regex.

Comment: Also, you didn't actually escape it - since it's a string, you need to escape the escape character, because right now this produces a string with a literal `$` in it (and that doesn't have a special meaning in strings to begin with).